# Safe bool multiple conversions ambiguity

Tags: c++, safe-bool-idiom

I have to implement safe bool idiom in order to support compilers that do not have `explicit` keyword (MSVC 2012 for example). The class that should be checkable for bool is modelling a pointer to many classes and therefore it should be convertible to these pointers. The following code illustrates the idea:

```
// Uncomment this line to change implementation to 'safe bool'
// #define _COMPILER_NO_EXPLICIT

#if !defined(_COMPILER_NO_EXPLICIT)
#define OPERATOR_BOOL_MYTYPE(...)
#define OPERATOR_BOOL_IMPLEMENTATION(...) \
    public: \
            explicit operator bool() const noexcept \
            { \
                    return __VA_ARGS__; \
            }
#else
#define OPERATOR_BOOL_MYTYPE(...) \
    private: \
            void safe_bool() {}; \
            typedef __VA_ARGS__ safe_bool_my_type_t; \
            typedef void (safe_bool_my_type_t::*safe_bool_t)()

#define OPERATOR_BOOL_IMPLEMENTATION(...) \
    public: \
            operator safe_bool_t() const noexcept \
            { \
                    return __VA_ARGS__ ? \
                            &safe_bool_my_type_t::safe_bool : \
                            nullptr; \
            }
#endif


class Convertible
{
public:
    operator int*() const
    { return nullptr; }

    operator double*() const
    { return nullptr; }

    OPERATOR_BOOL_MYTYPE(Convertible);
    OPERATOR_BOOL_IMPLEMENTATION(false);
};


int main(void)
{
    Convertible a;
    if (a)
    {
        // this 'if' statement introduces compilation error
        // in 'safe bool' implementation
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If we use `explicit operator bool()`-based implementation everything works fine. The problem is actually in ambiguous convertibility in "safe bool" based implementation. How should it be solved?

**Note:** Consider bool conversion implementation to be independent from other to-pointer conversion implementations. If it is not possible give me a clue how to implement it in dependent case e.g. if `Convertible` evaluates to true iff one of the other conversion operators are returning non null value.

**UPD:** I believe there is a way that makes one implicit conversion to be more preferable than all the other.

Comment: Did you consider using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/explicit_operator_bool.html ?

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed the boost code. It actually does things in the same way and therefore suffers from the same problems :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* you need to have implicit conversion to other pointer types?  If you don't need that, the problem will go away.

And if you do need implicit conversion to a pointer type, the problem seems moot: you don't need to convert to bool, because converting to a pointer will also yield a value which can be truth-tested (just like a regular raw pointer).

But you are still left with the ambiguous conversion due to the fact that you have operators for both `int*` and `double*`.  This part probably warrants a redesign, because it's not clear how you can expect to have a single value be implicitly convertible to multiple unrelated pointer types.

Comment: Yes, this actually is my problem :)

Comment: @svv: You mean your problem is you have a fundamentally flawed design?  OK, let's fix it!  How about instead of implicit casts to various pointer types, just have one possible pointer type?  Or, have a template function where the caller has to specify, like `template <T> T* as()`?

Comment: I should not change the clients code and I can force it to use the new method only if the method gets to be used implicitly.

Comment: OK, what exactly does the client code look like, and what behaviors does it rely upon now?

Comment: Well, you gave me a good idea. Everything worked fine till the latest changes. All conversion functions were implemented and worked somehow (but i'm not sure that they were called as intended, as I only compile, not run the code in MSVC 2012 environment). I'll check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no good solution. I've found one that partially meets my requirements and managed other requirements to be weaken.

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast the set and order of implicit conversions is the following:

> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence
>
> 2) zero or one user-defined conversion
>
> 3) zero or one standard conversion sequence

As both types of conversions from the question are user-defined and both allows further standard conversion to `bool` I've decided to change the `operator int*()` and `operator double*()` conversion functions to some other `operator Ptr<int>()` and `operator Ptr<double>` where `Ptr<T>` is a template class that behaves the same as a raw pointer does. Particularly it is convertible to bool but this doesn't matter as it is the second user conversion and therefore it is forbidden. So the only conversion to `bool` exists (which is from 'safe bool' implementation).

The drawback of this solution is that the clients code is required either to change interfaces or to perform explicit cast to raw pointer.